# Angular - Unselect all Checkbox

Tags: html, angular, checkbox, unselect

I was able to successfully `Add Select All` functionality when checkbox is clicked. However I am unable to `Uncheck All` when all items are already selected

Here is the link to code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-all-aota2app.component.html

Comment: Your link shows a 404 - include the code in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `unselectAll()` has never been called

```
<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="selected = !selected" [ngModel]="checked">Check/ Uncheck</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what did you do here?

Comment: em... because u need to change the value of `selected`, which update all your checkbox